# VBA: Protecting Shape Objects only

Tags: excel, vba

I read quite a few posts but didn't find anything similar to what I'm trying to achieve. I basically have a few `Shape` objects in my worksheet which have macros assigned to them. I would like to protect these objects using VBA so users can interact with them but not edit them in any way. I however, would like the users(and my VBA) to be able to freely manipulate the rest of the workbook as they like.

I tried `ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True` but the problem is that the usability of the rest of the application is quite limited as well. For example I have a checkbox that hides/unhides a range of cells but when the sheet is protected, I cannot execute the macro and I get an exception. Is there a way to protect the `Shape` objects only and basically leave the rest of the workbook unrestricted as if the sheet was unprotected?

Thanks,
Dimitar

Comment: Have you tried to run the protection through review, instead of programatically? It gives you a list of options - check for shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the other parameters, you will get their default values. Do something like this instead:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, _
                    Contents:=False, _
                    Scenarios:=False, _
                    UserInterfaceOnly:=False, _
                    AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
                    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                    AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
                    AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
                    AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
                    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
                    AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
                    AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
                    AllowSorting:=True, _
                    AllowFiltering:=True, _
                    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

In Review -> Protect sheet -> You want everything except "Edit Objects" checked (So users can still do everything), then create a password. This lets people do everything except edit objects - which IIRC, shapes are.

[image]

If you're hellbent on doing this with VBA, you can quickly record a macro with a similar lock, see what it looks like, and edit from there.

Edit: I just realized there are other objects you're trying to allow. In that case, I'd consider an on-change event, and when one of the shapes you're trying to protect get changed, hit undo